# Как подключить файл, находящийся в параллельный папке?

Tags: python

У меня такая структура папок(все init с двумя нижними чертами по обоим сторонам):

main.py

scraper

---**init**.py

---Page

------**init**.py

------Page.py

---BookPage

------**init**.py

------BookPage.py

---MainPage

------**init**.py

------MainPage.py

Вопрос: как мне импортировать Page в BookPage? В интернете предлагают изменить path. Можно ли сделать это по другому?

Вот мой главный **init**.py

```py
from .Page import Page
from .MainPage import MainPage
from .BookPage import BookPage
```

Вот другие
1

```py
from .BookPage import BookPage
```

2

```py
from .MainPage import MainPage
```

3

```py
from .Page import Page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, попробуйте в файле BookPage.py:

```py
from ..Page import Page
```

Количество точек означает, на сколько "уровней" вверх нужно подняться, где одна точка – нуль (то есть, остаться на том же "уровне", где находится исходный файл)

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.